# 'Related' sidebar has blank links that go directly to answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, sidebar

I was browsing around on a few recent questions when this caught my eye:

[image: Blank sidebar links]

- Those are blank links.
- Clicking the blank ones takes me directly to **answers**.
- The vote counts represent the answer's count (rather than the question's count).
- The link with words takes me to a question

I didn't think that the Related tab could link directly to answers? That may be the bug, but if this is meant to be a new feature, then there should at least be text next to the vote counts.

[Here is the question in question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/318217/28182). I haven't been able to find another example just yet.

Comment: That's weird. I don't see anything wrong when I go to that linked question - all the related links work fine. Maybe it's a browser issue? I'm using Chrome v61.0.3163.91.

Comment: I was able to reproduce earlier today but not anymore.

Comment: [Looks like its been fixed.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300893/why-are-there-links-to-answers-in-the-related-questions-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has now been fixed:

> A recent refactor of how we do Elastic searches for related questions was referencing the wrong site (using `Current.Site` rather than a site passed to the operation) during the refresh process for a question. This led to seemingly random post identifiers being used for the related questions. When we came to render the URL it went one of a few ways:
>
> - It couldn't find the question and so ignored it
> - The `PostId` was actually that of an answer and so it didn't have a title
> - The `PostId` was that of another type of post used for things like help posts (which are localized)
>
> Eurgh. We've fixed it, purged caches and all is now well.
>
> Thanks for the heads up <3
>   <sub>- [Dean Ward ♦ - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300893/why-are-there-links-to-answers-in-the-related-questions-list)</sub>